# Excel, when opening large html tables, the colspan tag is ignored

Tags: export-to-excel

There are large tables (300,000 rows) described as an HTML document. The beginning of the document is interpreted correctly, but at some point the columns begin to move. It seems that at some point the colspan tag begins to be ignored.

That is, the table is described like this

```
    <html>
    <table border="2" rules="all">
       <col width="50">
       <col width="50">
       <col width="50">
       <col width="50">
       <col width="50">
       <col width="50">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>col 1</th>
        <th>col 2</th>
        <th colspan="3" >col 3</th>
        <th>col 4</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td colspan="3">3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td colspan="3">7</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td colspan="3">11</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td colspan="3">15</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td colspan="3">19</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr></tbody>
    </table>
    </html>
```

it turns out

```
_____________________________________________
| col 1 | col 2 |       col 3       | col 4 |
---------------------------------------------
| 1     | 2     | 3                 |       |
| 1     | 2     | 3                 | 4     |
| 1     | 2     | 3                 | 4     |
... ~20 000 - 250 000
| 1     | 2     | 3     |     |     | 4     |
| 1     | 2     | 3     |     |     | 4     |
---------------------------------------------
```

there must be

```
_____________________________________________
| col 1 | col 2 |       col 3       | col 4 |
---------------------------------------------
| 1     | 2     | 3                 |       |
| 1     | 2     | 3                 | 4     |
| 1     | 2     | 3                 | 4     |
... ~20 000 - 250 000
| 1     | 2     | 3                 | 4     |
| 1     | 2     | 3                 | 4     |
---------------------------------------------
```

I convert HTML to Excel (xlsx\xlsb) using VBS, but the same effect will be if you just open the document in Excel and let it be recognized. I use excel 2019

VBS script for checking

```
dim objFSO, objFile, CNT

CNT = 100000

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("c:\raw.html", True)

objFile.WriteLine("<html><table border=2 rules='all'><col width=50><col width=50><col width=50><col width=50><col width=50><col width=50><thead><tr><th>col 1</th><th>col 2</th><th colspan=3 >col 3</th><th>col 4</th></tr></thead><tbody>")

For i = 1 To CNT
    objFile.WriteLine("<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td colspan=3>3</td><td>4</td></tr>")
Next

objFile.WriteLine("</tbody></table></html>")
objFile.Close

WScript.StdOut.Write "Raw file written: " & CNT & " lines. Star conversion..." & vbCrLf

dim app, wbk
dim indx

Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wbk = app.Workbooks.Open("c:\raw.html")
app.DisplayAlerts = False

wbk.SaveAs "c:\conv.xlsx", 51

WScript.StdOut.Write "The file has been converted. Star checks..." & vbCrLf

set sht1 = wbk.Sheets(1)

indx = 1
For Each cell In sht1.Range("C:C")
    
    If not cell.MergeCells Then
        WScript.StdOut.Write "Error in line " & indx & vbCrLf
        Exit For
    End If
    
    indx = indx + 1
    
    if indx > CNT Then
      WScript.StdOut.Write "Everything is fine" & vbCrLf
      Exit For
    End If
    
Next
   
wbk.Close False
app.Quit

set sht1 = Nothing
set wbk = Nothing
set app = Nothing
```

Comment: I would imagine there is an error somewhere in the html. This can cause havoc.  A missing td or tr open or close tag.  an extra div or span . all can cause chaos.  Difficult to track down with 300,000 entries.

Comment: I keep digging. I wrote a small script (added to the post) that writes HTML for 100,000 identical lines, converts it to Excel and immediately checks all cells. And it consistently breaks at line 32766.

Comment: Your hitting a limit.  32766 is not a random number it is a byte limit (do a search).  Find a way of creating smaller tables, your tables are too large.